# XML to XSL mapping - how to check the length of the element code's value - string(length)

Tags: xml, xslt

To start with the XML file I am using is as below

```
 **<composite code="ReceivedQty">
        <element code="CODE">
            <value>**00228298150-004**</value>
        </element>
        <element code="DATE">
            <value>11-19-2014</value>
        </element>
        <element code="RECQTY">
            <value>0</value>
        </element>
        <element code="NOTES">
            <value>004A</value>
        </element>

    </composite>**
    **<composite code="ReceivedQty">
        <element code="CODE">
            <value>**00228298150**</value>
        </element>
        <element code="DATE">
            <value>11-19-2014_11-19-2014</value>
        </element>
        <element code="RECQTY">
            <value>0_0</value>
        </element>
        <element code="NOTES">
            <value>new003AAA%#$^003B</value>
        </element>
    </composite>**
```

As seen in the XML file above, the `<element code="CODE">` has two values `00228298150` and `00228298150-004`.

The corresponding XSL file code is

```
        <xsl:for-each select="//table[@section='detail']/loop">
                <xsl:variable name="ndcNumber">
                    <xsl:value-of select="segment/element[@name='Product/Service ID']/value"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="lineNumber">
                    <xsl:value-of select="segment/element[@name='Assigned Identification']/value"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="ndcLineNumber">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($ndcNumber,'-',$lineNumber)"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="receivedQty">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/envelope/segment[@code='ACK']/composite[@code='ReceivedQty' and element[@code='CODE' and value=$**ndcLineNumber**]]/element[@code='RECQTY']/value"/>
                </xsl:variable>
    </<xsl:for-each>
```

In the XSL file, When the variable "receivedOty" is defined, it is defined using xsl select value as ndcLinenumber (which is 15 digits). Hence when the HTML page is rendered, only the data of element code=CODE having value "00228298150-004" is shown on the page.

I want to add a code in XSL file, so that data for element code=CODE having value "00228298150" is also displayed on the HTML page.
`$ndcnumber` is (11 characters) and `$ndclinenumber` (15 characters)

So basically, right now I am just able to access and retrieve only one value either `ndcnumber` or `ndclinenumber`. I want that my XSL retrieves both values from the XML simultaneously.

Maybe by handling it in if else block. I was thinking I can find out the length of the element code value, that way i can check if length(value)>11 digits then use the variable ndclinenumber, otherwise use ndcnumber.

Anyone has any idea how I can go about this?? Thanks!!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why don't you minimize the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem?  -- To answer the question in the title: use the `string-length()` function.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k I did minimize it, is the question more clear to you now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "retrieves both values from the XML simultaneously", but consider using a key to look up the `composite` elements by their code value.

```
<xsl:key name="comp" 
         match="segment[@code='ACK']/composite[@code='ReceivedQty']" 
         use="element[@code='CODE']/value" />
```

Then your current `xsl:value-of` can be simplified to this

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('comp', $ndcLineNumber)/element[@code='RECQTY']/value"/>
```

Or course, you could then just add a second `xsl:value-of` to get the other value

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('comp', $ndcNumber)/element[@code='RECQTY']/value"/>
```

But consider using some template matching here. You could add an `xsl:apply-templates` like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('comp', $ndcLineNumber)|key('comp', $ndcNumber)" mode="test"/>
```

Then the template match would be like this:

```
<xsl:template match="composite" mode="test">
   <xsl:value-of select="element[@code='RECQTY']/value" />,
</xsl:template>
```

(The use of "mode" is probably unnecessary here, but I put it in just in case you had a separate template matching `composite` in your XSLT).